# Regluing a jumpdrive case to the jump drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Question: what can I uses as a glue and how should I apply it to the circuit board and case of my jump drive so the two stay together again?

---

Info:

I have a Corsair Flash Voyager. It's a lovely jump drive and the rubber casing is a down right brilliant idea. But I recently bent the drive and now all the glue that held the rubber case to the circuit board inside has broken off and there are times when I pull the drive out that I only get the case and the circuit board stays in the USB port.

I need a way to put new glue on to the drive so that this won't keep happening. I assumed probably some kind of silicon glue, but I wanted to be sure. I don't want to have to buy a new jump drive, so i didn't want to fry it with something i was uncertain about. But also, I don't know what kind of silicon glue there is out there. hence my asking.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think anything that doesn't need to be mixed, or doesn't come with a solvent primer would be fine. Most glue is non-conductive, and there are various brands of "secure" jumpdrives where part of the security is to encase the chip in a solid block of glue.

I'd probably use plain old superglue.

Comment: Superglue is what I have always used

Comment: **Comment from an anonymous user:** I'd probably would use a plain old superglue or sturdy elmers glue. Note that ***using a hot glue gun could damage, if not melt, your usb drive.***